# how to use nse in python

Tags: python, nmap

how to use nse in python? for example

```
nmap -p80 google.com --script=http-enum
Output: 
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
| http-enum: 
|_  /partners/: Potentially interesting folder
```

Python:

```
nm.scan('google.com', arguments=f'-p80 --script=http-enum')
Output:
{'142.250.186.142': {'nmap': {'command_line': 'nmap -oX - -p80 --script=http-enum 142.250.186.142', 'scaninfo': {'tcp': {'method': 'connect', 'services': '80'}}, 'scanstats': {'timestr': 'Tue Jul 12 07:38:13 2022', 'elapsed': '11.03', 'uphosts': '1', 'downhosts': '0', 'totalhosts': '1'}}, 'scan': {'142.250.186.142': {'hostnames': [{'name': 'fra24s07-in-f14.1e100.net', 'type': 'PTR'}], 'addresses': {'ipv4': '142.250.186.142'}, 'vendor': {}, 'status': {'state': 'up', 'reason': 'syn-ack'}, 'tcp': {80: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'http', 'product': '', 'version': '', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '3', 'cpe': ''}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When called in python, looks like it returns a dictionary with all the info. To get specific info you can access these attributes separately as shown in the [docs](https://xael.org/pages/python-nmap-en.html). If instead, you want to run the same command on the command line from a python script you can use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
command = "nmap -p80 google.com --script=http-enum"
subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '))
```

Comment: is it possible to command execution via subproccess? I mean some not good commands because i have user input

Comment: @spot, yes, you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) in the python docs